# while loop : where can i find the differents meanings of while like -eq -> [ $ex -eq 1 ]; do ?

Tags: shell-script

I'm searching the multiples options and their significance with while [ $ -xy 1 ], but I don't know where can I get it...
How can I do ?

Someone to help me ?

Comment: The `[ .. ]` construct in this context is a form of the `test` command: see `man test`.

Comment: Or simply `man [` will work on many systems.

Comment: Why not use a search engine for this?

Comment: @sjsam presumably because google treats the `-` prefix as "do not include in search results," so a search for `-eq` won't return any results. You need to know the magic words, e.g. "conditional expressions in bash." Also, FYI, `[` is a shell built-in in some shells (notably `bash`), so `man [` or `man test` might *not* get you the right list.

Comment: If `man [` and `man test` don't give you what you want, try `man sh` or `man bash`, or search for "unix man page sh" or "bash".                P.S. You should always quote your shell variable references (e.g., `"$ex"`) unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re sure you know what you’re doing.

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflow has a documentation section for [Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bash/topics). What you're asking about is in [control structures](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bash/topics?page=2&tab=popular). If something's missing, you can order topics (with the blue button on the right):

[image]

Comment: indeed, our own site has a good [reference section for bash](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/bash/info)